# Parsing XML CDATA with PHP

Tags: php, xml, rss

I have a little problem that I can't figure out how to solve.
I have an XML (actually it's RSS) file that I'm trying to parse with PHP, but the CDATA tag come out blank.

Here's the [XML](http://pastebin.com/m97eca7e) Code
and here's the [PHP file](http://pastebin.com/d24ae19fd)

Everything works fine, except that the description tag is not printing.
I would be very grateful if some one could help.

Comment: Can you also post the part of code that's in charge of the parsing of the XML data ? Maybe the bug is in the code, and not in the data ^^

Comment: Do you still have the XML and PHP code? Pastebin has deleted your entries. If you have them, could you edit the question to bring them back (don't put them back on pastebin, put them into the question text instead.) If you can't, the question will be deleted. Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just out of curiosity, after getting your XML *(I hope I didnt't destroy it in the process -- I'll see if I can edit the OP to correct it)* :

- did you cast the description to a string ?

What I mean is you could use this :

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item) {
    var_dump($item->description);
}
```

But it would only get you that :

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[5]
object(SimpleXMLElement)[3]
```

Which is not that nice...

You need to cast the data to string, like this :

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item) {
    var_dump((string)$item->description);
}
```

And you get the descriptions :

```
string '

This is one of the content that I need printed on the screen, but nothing is happening. Please, please...output something... <br /><br /> <b>Showing</b>: 2 weeks<br /> <b>Starting On</b>: August 7, 2009 <br /> <b>Posted On</b>: August 7, 2009 <br />
<a href="http://www.mysite.com">click to view</a> 
            ' (length=329)

string '

Another content...This is another of the content that I need printed on the screen, but nothing is happening. Please, please...output something... <br /><br /> <b>Showing</b>: 2 weeks<br /> Starting On: August 7, 2009 <br /> <b>Posted On</b>: August 7, 2009
; 
               ' (length=303)
```

*(Using `trim` on those might prove useful, btw, if you XML is indented)*

Else... Well, we'll probably need your php code (at least, would be useful to know how you are getting to the `description` tag **;-)** )

---

EDIT

Thanks for the reformated XML !

If I go to pastebin, in the textarea at the bottom of the page, there is a white space at the beginning of the XML, before the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

If you have that one in your real XML data, it will be a source of problem : it is not valid XMl (the XML declaration has to be the **first** thing in the XML data).

You'll get errors like this one :

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 1: parser error : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
```

Can you check that ?

And, if the problem is here, you should activate [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and [`display_errors`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) ;-) That would help !

---

EDIT after taking a look at the PHP file :

In your for loop, you are doing this to get your description data :

```
$item_desc = $x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

description doesn't contain any childNode, I'd say ; what about using it's nodeValue directly ?

Like this :

```
$item_desc = $x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

It seems to be working better this way :-)

As a sidenote, you could probably do the same for other tags, I suppose ; for instance, this seems to be working too :

```
$item_title=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$item_link=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

What does this give you ?

---

Another EDIT : and here is the code I would probably use :

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->loadXML($str);         // I changed that because I have the XML data in a string

//get elements from "<channel>"
$channel = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0);
$channel_title = $channel->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$channel_link = $channel->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue;
$channel_desc = $channel->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue;

//output elements from "<channel>"
echo "<p><a href='" . $channel_link . "'>" . $channel_title . "</a>";
echo "<br />";
echo $channel_desc . "</p>";

//get and output "<item>" elements
$x = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');
for ($i=0 ; $i<=1 ; $i++) {
    $item_title = $x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $item_link = $x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $item_desc = $x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    echo ("<p><a href='" . $item_link
    . "'>" . $item_title . "</a>");
    echo ("<br />");
    echo ($item_desc . "</p>");
    echo' <p />';
}
```

Note I have the XML data in a string, and I don't need to fetch it from an URL, so I'm using the `loadXML` method and not `load`.

The major difference is that I removed some childNodes accesses, that I feel were not necessary.

Does this seem OK to you ?

Comment: There's no blank space...I guess it's from your side. The XML declaration is on the very first line.

Comment: Maybe a problem with Pastebin, or, as you say, on my side ; I've removed it and it's OK now -- I've edited my answer quite a couple of times (after you gave XML, and then, after you gave PHP code, and the another time for a "final" solution), to provide more informations ; hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks Pascal for your help, but where did you get the $str you are loading 'loadXML($str) ?

Could you tell how I can change my code to load string too instead?

Comment: I copied the XML string you posted on pastebin, and pasted it into a string, stored in the variable called $str. You should be able to keep loading your XML data with load and the URL you're using... But I couldn't do that, as "http://www.mysite.com/sample.rss" (the URL you gave in your PHP code on pastebin) is obviously not the real URL to the real RSS data ^^ So I just used a string, containing the XML you're using... And working with loadHTML to initialize the DOMDocument from a string, and not from a file like you did with load.

Comment: Hey Pascal, did I tell you you were an awesome individual? Your code is working like magic. Thanks for your precious time and God bless you.

You've been marvellous :))))

Comment: thank you for such a detailed response! very useful