# Accessing tags inside CDATA in XML using PHP

Tags: php, xml, cdata

I am confused. How can I access tags inside CDATA?

XML Code:

```
<body>
<block>
<![CDATA[ 
     <font color="#FFCC53" size="+6"><b>Latest News Updates</b></font>
     <font color="#AAAAAA">HTML Formatted Text Fields</font>            
]]>                         
</block>
</body>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
     $xml = simplexml_load_file("main.xml");
     print (  $xml->smallTextList[0]->item[0]->textBody[0]->font[0] ) ;
?>
```

I am using this, but I am getting a blank screen....

Comment: Possible solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246732/parsing-xml-cdata-with-php

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your font tags are *inside* of CDATA. Since CDATA stands for "Compiled Data", PHP should treat it as a "block of non-parsed data." It should not (and cannot) let you read those as tags. You'll probably have to do something like:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("main.xml");
$inner = simplexml_load_string( 
 '<fk>' . // you have to wrap the CDATA in a tag, otherwise it will break.
      // not sure about asXML. You may be able to get away without it.
      $xml->block[0]->asXML() . 
 '</fk>'
 );
print $inner->font[0];
```

Your problem, of course, is that CDATA will let things in which are not valid XML, like `<` or `>`, but this seems to be your best option...

Comment: I have it and got this error message.Fatal error: Call to a member function asXML() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\xml\forum\1.php on line 7

Comment: @junaid That is more or less copied from your code above, it means that your `smallTextList[0]->item` did not exist.