# Parse CDATA with simplexml php

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have xml file like

```
<offer>
   <WEB>.........</WEB>
   <URL>...............</URL>
   <![CDATA[
       <TITLE>some ......</TITLE>
   ]]>
   <SOLD_AMOUNT>0</SOLD_AMOUNT>
   <IMAGE>.....l_offer_438.jpg</IMAGE>
   <CITY>town.....</CITY>
   <DISCOUNT>50</DISCOUNT>
   <ORIGINAL_PRICE>1405</ORIGINAL_PRICE>
   <FINAL_PRICE>702</FINAL_PRICE>
   <DEAL_END>1323122399</DEAL_END>
</offer>
```

how can i parse CDATA section

```
$sxe = simplexml_load_file($xml,null,LIBXML_NOCDATA);
print_r($sxe);
```

this way it does not working

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [offer] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [WEB] => ghfghfgh
                    [URL] => fghfgh
                    [SOLD_AMOUNT] => 0
                    [IMAGE] => fghfghfgh
                    [CITY] => dfgdfgdfg
                    [DISCOUNT] => 50
                    [ORIGINAL_PRICE] => 1405
                    [FINAL_PRICE] => 702
                    [DEAL_END] => 1323122399
                    [TITLE] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                        )

                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [WEB] => dfgdgdfgdfg
                    [URL] => fghfghfg
                    [SOLD_AMOUNT] => 0
                    [IMAGE] => dfgdfg_offer_433.jpg
                    [CITY] => dfgdfgdg
                    [DISCOUNT] => 31
                    [ORIGINAL_PRICE] => 259
                    [FINAL_PRICE] => 179
                    [DEAL_END] => 1323122399
                    [TITLE] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                        )

                )
```

Comment: How exactly does it not work? Can you show the result of the `print_r` call?

Comment: You supplied `LIBXML_NOCDATA`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing tags inside CDATA in xml using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065740/accessing-tags-inside-cdata-in-xml-using-php)

Comment: to print the CDATA section you just do `echo $sxe[0];`

Comment: SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [offer] => Array
        (
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [WEB] => sdfsdfs
                    [URL] => dsfsdfsf.html
                    [SOLD_AMOUNT] => 0
                    [IMAGE] => l_offer_438.jpg
                    [CITY] => town
                    [DISCOUNT] => 50
                    [ORIGINAL_PRICE] => 1405
                    [FINAL_PRICE] => 702
                    [DEAL_END] => 1323122399
                    [TITLE] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                        )

)

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674322/how-to-get-values-inside-cdatavalues-using-php-dom

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sxe = simplexml_load_file($xml,null);
print_r($sxe);
```

Comment: and what's that supposed to do? More words please.

Comment: then insert the strings in mysql table

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970602/php-how-to-handle-cdata-with-simplexmlelement