# What to parse data with <![CDATA[]]> in XML File?

Tags: php, xml

i have used one xml file in that file there is one tag like

```
<image><![CDATA[ _abc.jpg ]]></image>

$xml = simplexml_load_file('test1.xml');
foreach($xml as $product)
        {
            echo $product->image;
        }
```

Please tell me how to parse data with  in php?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing XML CDATA with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246732/parsing-xml-cdata-with-php)

Comment: You can use `LIBXML_NOCDATA` as option into `simplexml_load_file`

Answer (score 0):

You could make of [`simplexml_load_string`][1] with these `libxml` options

```
<?php
$xml='<image><![CDATA[ _abc.jpg ]]></image>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml,'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA | LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
print_r($xml);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] =>  _abc.jpg 
)
```

To just print the `_abc.jpg` , Just do this. `echo $xml[0];`
[1]: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php